# How to save textarea values in a list onclick of button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to add a save feature to my journal project which is just a static website.

Basically, there are three parts.

1. The textarea
2. Save button
3. Div to store logs

What I want to achieve is if I click on the save button, it will save the entry in a bullet list... If I click the save button again, it will create another entry below it, and so on.

The above is just the start.. after that I plan to be able to save that list value in local storage, so the next time I open the tool, the list should still be there and I should be able to add more to it.

And another bonus if I can add the timestamp (date and time) preceding each logs.
for example:

- 03/11/2022 5:00 AM - Note here
- 03/15/2022 9:32 AM - Note here
- 03/24/2022 7:15 AM - Note here

How do I go about to build this? Right now I only have HTML and CSS to show for.. but I'm hoping someone can show me how it can be achieved. Please see my code below:

```html
<textarea id="textarea3" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>

<button id="save-btn">Save textarea</button>

<div id="logs">

    <ul>
        <li></li>
    </ul>    

</div>
```

Apologies for so many queries... but thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: I don't understand how you want to save the values in a readable bullet list? I mean how to separate the values in the text area?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of description, I will update it now. Anyways, what I meant to say was to save each entry in a bullet list.

Comment: u mean if the button is double-clicked then create another div?

Comment: Doesn't really need to create another div, just another bullet. Simply put, 1 bullet for each entry (each save).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very basic implementation of what you are trying to do. Essentially there are these steps you need to take:

- attach an `onclick` [event listener](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) to your save button using its ID whenever the HTML has loaded. See [DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event).
- when the button is clicked get the text from the [`<textarea>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp) using it's ID and `value` property
- get the list using its ID and create a new list item `<li>`
- assign the text from the textarea to the list item
- get timestamp using [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

```js
/**
 * This function handles the onclick event meaning it will be called whenever the button is clicked.
 */
function onSave() {
  // get textarea element
  const textArea = document.getElementById("textarea3");
  // retrieve the value within it
  const note = textArea.value;
  // add the note to the list
  addNote(note);
}

/**
 * This function adds a new note to the list of notes with a timestamp.
 * @param {string} noteText text to be added to list
 */
function addNote(noteText) {
  // get the list
  const logList = document.getElementById("log-list");
  // create a new list item
  const listItem = document.createElement("li");
  // now set the text for this list item using a timestamp and the text provided as parameter
  listItem.textContent = `${new Date().toLocaleString("en-US")}  -  ${noteText}`;
  // at this stage the list element is not yet added to the list, so add it at the bottom of the list now
  logList.appendChild(listItem);
}

// wait until all the HTML has been loaded!
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  // get the button element
  const saveBtn = document.getElementById("save-btn");
  // attach an event listener for the "click" event. Every time the button i clicked onSave() should be called
  saveBtn.addEventListener("click", onSave)
});
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea3" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>

<button id="save-btn">Save textarea</button>

<div id="logs">
  <ul id="log-list">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is exactly what I'm looking for. I'll go ahead and work on it now. Thank you, thank you ^_^

Comment: No worries. I've included some links to the Documentation and w3 schools now for some of the stuff I've mentioned and used for you to read on.